# C-strings null terminating character \0 modification

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

Is the null character at the end of a C-string always constant and cannot be modified? Meaning, can the null character /0 at the end of a C-string be modified by the programmer? Or is it constant and cannot be removed. Example : 'Steak' is in a cstring and it has \0 at position 5. When 'steak' is modified, can we remove the \0 completely?

Comment: It's just a character in storage.  It can be modified (at your peril) like any other character.  But it's important to have it there to mark the end of a standard C string, since otherwise the length of the string would have to be passed separately to string functions.

Comment: The question itself is invalid. A C-string is a string that is zero-terminated. If you remove the 0, then it's no longer a C-string and you no longer can use it with standard string functions. If you have experience with Pascal: an analogy would be "can the length be removed from a Pascal string?" -- pretty much the same answers as given here.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is the null character at the end of a C-string always constant and cannot be modified?*

**No** in case we are talking about arrays of characters (static or dynamic), but *yes* if you mean a constant string literal such as:

```
const char* str = "steak";
```

> *can the null character /0 at the end of a C-string be modified by the programmer?*

**Yes** as long as the memory is not read-only.

> *can we remove the \0 completely?*

**Yes.** But then if you use this string with a function that expects `'\0'` at the, the *behavior is undefined*

Comment: It might be worthwhile to note that because literal C strings are constant, they can't be modified. When a string is dynamically allocated, though, you're certainly correct.

Comment: In other words, just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.

Answer (score 0):

If the C-string is the return value of the `c_str()` or `data()` member functions of `std::string`, then the standard forbids the modification of the trailing `0` element. Of course, just because the standard forbids it doesn't mean that anything in C++ or its runtime environment will warn you about the violation. It's quite possible that you can write code which attempts to modify the trailing `0`, and it will execute without raising any alarms. However, it is also very likely that things will go wrong in unpredictably strange ways.

So don't do it.